# Android how to add dynamic behaviours to a listview of edittexts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

I am attempting to achieve a particular behavior with Edittexts.

**What I wish to achieve**:

The user will be presented with a single EditText.  When the focus is placed into this EditText, I wish to create another EditText below that one without interrupting the user's typing. Upon going to the next EditText, yet another EditText will be created and placed below that.  This will continue until the user has filled in all they wish to fill in.
If any EditText (with the exception of the last one) is empty, that EditText should be deleted and removed from the view.

**Issues I have faced thus far**:

I have tried to use Listeners such as TextWatchers, setOnEditorActionListener, and onFocusChangeListeners.  Each time I use one, though, I tend to have an issue with improper representation of data within the list.

**Questions**:

- What sort of listener would be most appropriate for EditTexts in this situation?
- What is proper method of adding, removing, or notifying a change in the adapter?

**Adapter Class**:

```
public class TwitterUserNameAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<String> twitterUserNames;

    public TwitterUserNameAdapter(){
        this.twitterUserNames = new ArrayList<>();
        twitterUserNames.add("");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return twitterUserNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return twitterUserNames.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_user_input_field, parent, false);
        }

        final EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etTwitterUserName);
        usernameEditText.setText(twitterUserNames.get(position));


        TextWatcher lastEditTextBehavior = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().isEmpty()){
                    twitterUserNames.set(position, s.toString());
                    twitterUserNames.add("");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

        TextWatcher standardEditTextBehavior = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().isEmpty()){
                    twitterUserNames.set(position, s.toString());
                    removeItem(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

        if (position == twitterUserNames.size() - 1) {
            usernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(lastEditTextBehavior);
        } else {
            usernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(standardEditTextBehavior);
        }

        String debugString = "";
        for (String username : twitterUserNames) {
            debugString += "\"" + username + "\" ";
        }
        Log.d("TAG", debugString);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void addNewItem() {
        twitterUserNames.add("");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setItem(int index, String value) {
        twitterUserNames.set(index, value);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeItem(int index) {
        twitterUserNames.remove(index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**List View Layout Item XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tilTwitterUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\@"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etTwitterUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:hint="Twitter User Name"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Activity XML**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context="com.github.jackkell.mimicryproject.mainactivities.ImpersonatorCreationActivity"
    android:id="@+id/ImpersonatorCreation" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilImpersonatorName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etImpersonatorName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Impersonator Name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTwitterUsernames"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tilImpersonatorName">
    </ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreateImpersonator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lvTwitterUsernames"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lvTwitterUsernames"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lvTwitterUsernames">
    </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can change visibility of a view (visible/gone). e.g. when edittext1 get focus display edittext2 on UI screen and so on.

Comment: The goal is too add the edit texts to the list view dynamically/programmatically. Therefore a solution such as turning edittexts on and off is not an option although this could work if the forum had a finite number of edittexts.